# Htmlunit get facebook access token

Tags: eclipse, facebook, facebook-graph-api, htmlunit

I want to get facebook's access token by code (and i dont have application)
So I use the graph api explorer. And i thought using htmlunit I will succeed in retrieving the access token but i can't, and I don't understand why, Here is what i wrote :

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/MYID/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.2");
final HtmlDivision div = page.getHtmlElementById("access_token");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get any Access Token without any App. And the API Explorer is a browser tool, you can´t use it like that. Check out the Facebook docs about how to authorize a User properly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2